# Organize files in Web Inspector

Tags: apache, dom, web, resources, web-inspector

## The problem:

Whenever I use the Web Inspector (mostly in Safari) and take a look at the resources used by a website it often occurs that the resources are well organized in directories. However when I open the Web Inspector on my own website all the files seem to be ordered randomly.

**Example:**

[image: Web Inspector Example]

***Left**: [Twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com), **Right**: My Website*

---

## Expected result:

I'm looking for a way to get the resources of my website organized the same way as Twitter has accomplished in the given example.

**Possible solutions (that I've already tried):**

- The most logical answer would be to organize all the files in directories. I have already placed all CSS files in a folder called CSS, I did the same for images, fonts, etc.
- I have created a sitemap linking to all these files bus this doesn't work either.
- I assume that it has nothing to do with the amount files. The problem occurs on website with 1-10 files, but also on bigger website with more files.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't seem to work" if you put your files in directories? What kind of problems do you run into?

Comment: The use of sitemap.xml doesn't seems to work.
I even renamed my directories to the directories from the image but this also didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean, what goes wrong. "Doesn't seem to work" is not a good description of any problem. What do you expect to happen and what does really happen?

Comment: If you open the source of a webpage, you will see something similar to one of the two images above. But the difference in the images is, is that some files are organized in directories (image 1) and some are not (image 2).
I would like to know, how i can organize my files in the source navigator.